# Converter valores monetários "R$" para tipo double

Tags: r, double

Olá, eu estou com diversos arquivos CSV, nos quais foram armazenados em algumas colunas valores monetários em real ex: "R$ 1.986,00". Contudo, pretendo passar todos os CSV para o SQLite e, em seguida, analisar os dados no Power BI. Sendo assim, em vez de exportar os dados do CSV para o SQLite no tipo caracter, gostaria de exportá-los como tipo double (acho que essa seria a opção apropriada, creio eu), com vista a facilitar o processo de tratamento de dados no Power BI.

Nesse contexto, gostaria de saber se há alguma função ou pacote no R que é possível transformar dados de um data.frame (importado de um CSV)  que estejam no formato monetário em real ("R$ 1.986,69") para tipo double ("1986.69")?

Segue o exemplo das colunas que estão armazenados no CSV. No caso concreto, serão cerca de 27 mil arquivos CSV, com estimativa de 20 milhões de linhas que serão consolidados no SQLite.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já, obrigado pelo apoio.

---

Depois da ajuda de @Rui Barradas, fiz um complementação na expressão regular para pegar diversas situações. Ficou assim, a título de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente aplicar a função `converte`a cada uma das colunas com os valores problemáticos.

```
converte <- function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", "\\.", gsub("R\\$|\\.", "", x)))

x <- "R$ 5.500,00"
converte(x)
#[1] 5500
```

Como as funções `sub` e `gsub` são vetorizadas, `converte` também o é e processa colunas inteiras.

Comment: No caso, tento por base a imagem que postei, eu só precisaria, então, escrever as seguintes etapas para que os dados do dataframe fossem alterados?:

`csv$salario_base <- sub(",", "\\.", gsub("R\\$|\\.", "", csv$salario_base))`


`csv$salaraio_vantagens <- sub(",", "\\.", gsub("R\\$|\\.", "", csv$salaraio_vantagens))`


`csv$salario_gratificacao <- sub(",", "\\.", gsub("R\\$|\\.", "", csv$salario_gratificacao))`

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Rui Barradas.  Ajudou muito.

Comment: @GeorgeSantiago Em resposta ao primeiro comentário, sim bastaria escrever isso mas a função `converte` é mais conveniente, evita escrever o mesmo código várias vezes. Quanto ao segundo comentário, de nada, é para isso que aqui estamos.